# asp net core: [FromRoute] and model binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

is it possible to bind a parameter from the url to a property of the DTO that is being Model Binded?

```
[Route("delivery/{document}")]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Delivery(DeliveryIn data)
{
    //...
}
```

This code with the following DTO always gives me document as null:

```
public class DeliveryIn
{
    [FromRoute]
    public string document{ get; set; }

    [Required]
    public decimal amount { get; set; }
}
```

Is it impossible to bind this property as I am trying? do I have to add it as an argument to the action?

Comment: How do you send the request?

Comment: Your example works totally fine

Comment: What do you mean by `bind a parameter from the body to a property of the DTO`? Based on your description, it seems you want to bind `document` from `route`, what do you mean by body? Do you want to bind `document` from route or body?

Comment: @TaoZhou I meant binding a parameter from the route, sorry. I edited the original question

Comment: so you want to bind `document` from url instead of request Body?

Comment: Did you try to run it and got some error or unexpected behavior? Because, as @Alexander said, your example should work just fine.